# Video stabilizing - tools, code, middleware, anything ! :)

Tags: video

So tonight I was going through my gadgets, sorting out all recorded videos from my Flip video camera, my first IPhone, my HTC Desire etc.

Most of it is pretty shaky handycam, and it would be great to be able to stabilize the videos by software. Using Google I found lots of software to stabilize videos, the most common solution being deshaker in virtualdub.

Which is nice if you want to stabilize one or two videos... but I'd like an automated solution for 100+ videos.
I assume that it's probably possible to do batch-processing in VirtualDub and to do it that way, but I'd rather have a program that I can point to a folder with videos, point to an output-folder and press 'go'. If one or more of the resulting videos are not up to personal quality standards, so be it, at least I'll have the rest.

I haven't found such a program. If anyone knows one, please respond :)
If not, what would be the best way to go about this ?
If I'll be doing this myself, I'd think I'd need to write a program (preferably C#, but any other language will be fine too) importing for example the deshake dll and apply it with some default parameter set to the input batch.

Anyone care to join me in thinking about this / making this work ? :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/156203/alternatives-to-y4mstabilizer-deshaking-video

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [DeShaker for VirtualDub](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm)? Some of the [DeShaker demos on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=deshaker&aq=f) show its output.

> Deshaker is a video stabilizer for VirtualDub. It eliminates camera shakiness and makes panning, rotation and zooming smoother.

It's not clear whether the source is available on this page, or anywhere else.

Comment: According to my post I have considered DeShaker for VirtualDub ;)

Comment: No problem, thanks for not making it to the 3rd line in the first post.